# Jquery AJAX is working but displayed message bugged

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In `changename.php` I have this DIV:

```
<div id="resultDiv"></div>
```

In the same file I have the PHP code:

```
<?php

include_once ('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
$postedname = $_POST['name'];
$safename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $postedname);

$checkname = "SELECT * from accounts where name='$safename' LIMIT 1";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $checkname);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($row) {
  echo 'Name is already taken!';
} else {

  $changename = "UPDATE accounts SET name='$safename' WHERE Name='$_SESSION[username]'";
  $query = mysqli_query($con, $changename);

  if($query)
  {
    echo 'Name is changed!';
    $_SESSION['username'] = $safename;
  }
}
}
?>
```

And this is my Jquery script (in a seperate file):

```
$(function(){

$("form").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var name = $('#inputName').val();


    $.post("changename.php", 
    {
        name: name
    },
    function(data)
    {
             $("#resultDiv").text(data);
        });
});
});
```

The code is just working fine, it successfully changes my name. If I want my name to be 'John', it successfully changes it in the DB.

The problem is, it's supposed to change the div with ID `resultDiv` to `Name is already taken!`. Instead of that, it takes the whole `changename.php` HTML code and puts it into that DIV. So instead of 1 line, I have 100+ lines of my page in there. So it looks like this:

https://gyazo.com/9320a5f15ed67a8ad9298d6172ab6909

Any idea why it's not just the message I want?

Comment: in your changename.php what ever html is there , it ll be fetched form ajax.

Comment: So I have to put the PHP code into a seperate file for AJAX?

Comment: You have 2 options, check the answer.

Comment: Quickest way is to add `return;` just before the last `}` in the PHP code you posted, assuming that the rest of the HTML page is generated after that.

Comment: Thanks, that worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax will fetch all data from file given as url for it.
If you want to avoid that, you have 2 options.

- Write condition in `changename.php` in such a way that only update to db part will be executed.
- On `changename.php` keep only required code to update to db.